# jQuery animation of SVG image - Move from current position to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to change the position of an SVG image with `transform: translate` and to animate this movement.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#svg-logo').addClass("moveToTop");
  }, 8000);

});
```

```css
#svg-logo {
  max-width: 45vw;
  transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
  &.moveToTop {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    max-width: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-1dae199 elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-id="1dae199" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="html.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <object id="svg-logo" type="image/svg+xml" data="file.svg"></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The problem**

On page load, the logo is in the middle of the screen. After 8 seconds I want to animate a movement to the top left position to place it as basic logo and make it smaller. How I can set the `translate(0,0)` as absolute values? Is it possible?

I tried also the `position:absolute;left:50px;top:50px` possibility, but I need the movement from the current position to position Y. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did this for you. You just have to change with your HTML and CSS, and the values you want the animation.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
               $('.move-box').animate({top: "10px", left: "10px" }); 
        },5000);
    });
```

```css
.move-box{
    width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="move-box"></div>
```